# Why is y not defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

In this code for some reason the variable `y` is not defined for the first `if` statement only.  I need to know why it says that `y` is not defined.  Also if you need code for finding `WOEID` here it is.

```
import urllib2

def make_word(words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += i
    return result

continents = ['asia', 'north%20america', 'south%20america', 'europe', 'asia', 'australia', 'antarctica']
a = raw_input('Put in a place: ')
a = a.lower()
if ' ' in a:
    for h in a:
        if h == ' ':
            y = a.replace(' ', '%20')

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/%s' % a).read()
f = page.find('Ohio')
if y not in continents:
    if f != -1:
        start = page.find('woeid="', f) + 7
        end = page.find('"', start)
        print 'The WOEID for %s: %s' % (a, page[start:end])
    if f == -1:
        f = page.find('United States')
        if f != -1:
            start = page.find('woeid="', f) + 7
            end = page.find('"', start)
            print 'The WOEID for %s: %s' % (a, page[start:end])
if y in continents:
    if f == -1:
        f = page.find('')
        start = page.find('woeid="', f) + 7
        print page[start:]
        end = page.find('"', start)
        print 'The WOEID for %s: %s' % (a, page[start:end])
```

Answer (score 3):

You only define `y` in very specific circumstances:

```
if ' ' in a:
    for h in a:
        if h == ' ':
            y = a.replace(' ', '%20')
```

So only if there is a space in `a` do you produce `y`.

Don't create a new variable here, and don't URL-encode manually. Use the [`urllib.quote()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) instead:

```
from urllib import quote

y = quote(a.lower())
```

You appear to be mixing `a` and `y` throughout your code. Perhaps you need to use more meaningful names here:

```
place = raw_input('Put in a place: ')
place_quoted = quote(place.lower())
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/%s' % place_quoted).read()
if place_quoted not in continents:
```

Comment: Maybe they don't know that python variables do not have any default value, like 0 or ''.

Comment: @Paul: even if it did have a default value, it'd not make sense in the context of the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

if ' ' in a: #This conditions fails in your code and the `y` variable is not initialized/ set.

if y not in continents: # when this line executes, it has no reference for y, throws the error "undefined"

Better initialize a default value at the start of your code.

Eg : y = None (or) handle your variable properly.